# Multi-line string in YAML containing quotes

Tags: string, yaml, silex

I have a YAML config file that can contain a bit of CSS for customization purposes.

```
css.custom: >
  .company-logo {
    height: 60px;
    padding-top: 15px;
  }
  .input[type=\"text\"] {
    background: white;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    border-radius: 3px;
  }
```

Which is then rendered in a file called `base.css.twig` like this:

```
{{ css.custom }}
```

My problem is that I can't get the quotes in `input[type=\"text\"]` to render correctly as the backslash is rendered literally and the quotes are rendered as `&quot;`. Has anyone figured how to render raw quotes successfully?

The resulting render:

```
input[type=&quot;text&quot;]
```

Comment: The YAML gives a key of `css.custom` but in Twig, you access a variable `css.customCss`. Also, your given Twig code is possibly not enough to recognize the error. are you in an `{% autoescape %}` environment? What happens if you remove the `|raw`?

Comment: My bad, i made an error in the example. I'll test it out and post the results with and without the raw filter.

Comment: @flyx turns out you were right. that was the problem all along! I was looking at the wrong place and the raw was missing!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use `{{ css.custom|raw }}`

I thought I was already using `raw` but I was wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot escape anything in YAML multi-line scalar strings. You don't have to escape the quotes, so you should leave out the `\`:

```
css.custom: >
  .company-logo {
    height: 60px;
    padding-top: 15px;
  }
  .input[type="text"] {
    background: white;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    border-radius: 3px;
  }
```

You should also consider if you really want the folding (`>`) and not the literal (`|`) style of multi-line scalars.

The [folding style is like literal style](http://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2796251):

> The folded style is denoted by the “>” indicator. It is similar to the literal style; however, folded scalars are subject to line folding.

and [the literal style](http://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2795688) doesn't have escaping:

> There is no way to escape characters inside literal scalars. This restricts them to printable characters. In addition, there is no way to break a long literal line.

Comment: This doesn't answer my question, though, as the quotes are being rendered as `&quot;`. Using `>` or `|` is the same for me. I actually think all in a single line suits the purpose better. It also doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: The change from `>` to `|` is optional, as I indicated. The important part is that you seem to be thinking you need to escape the quotes by putting a backquote before them, but in a folded/literal YAML string you cannot. (And if your processing software requires the backquote, than this has nothing to do with YAML and you mis-tagged the question).

Comment: I think we cannot assume that a question tagged with `yaml` can indeed be answered with YAML knowledge, because it might not be obvious for the OP that the problem is not YAML-related, and an answer telling them that is of course helpful.

Comment: @flyx I have been trying to clean up questions with [tag:yaml], where that just happens to be involved, but where it is irrelevant for the question as per the tag description), as irrelevant tags don't help the questioner and distract future searches from "real" YAML related questions. But it is like rowing against the stream, nobody seems to read tag descriptions.